# Hide specific rows using DataTables plugin?

Tags: jquery, datatable, html-table

I have a web page with a table that displays data from a database. There is a main `<tr>` being displayed and an additional `<tr>` that is hidden and only displays with jquery when the user clicks a button that is on the first main `<tr>`.

The problem that I am getting is when I use the datatables plugin, it finds all the rows and counts them, so I have 11 rows of data and 11 additional hidden rows under each main row. It then displays at the button of the table "Showing 1 to 10 of 22 entries". I don't want Datatables to count or see the hidden rows. I there a way to fix this problem. All `<tr>'s` have ID's and classes, so I thought there might be a simple way of sorting this data properly.

Also, when I do click the main `<tr>` to display the hidden `<tr`> it does not slide down under the main `<tr>` I clicked, instead It goes above all the main `<tr>'s`. Anyone know why?

[Datatables Site []>](http://datatables.net/index)

Answer (score 0):

the query you do to count the rows should use the ":visible" attribute. So your query should look something like:

```
var entries = $("tr:visible").length;
```